# Type list of MediaCodec.createDecoderByType (String type)

Tags: android, android-mediacodec

Where can I find the complete list of the type used in MediaCodec.createDecoderByType (String type)?

[Google's document](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaCodec.html#createDecoderByType(java.lang.String)) only gives a partial list.

Update[2015-06-03]

Per pskink's tip, I ran a piece of code to extract all the decode's MIME types on an Asus MeMO tablet. Here is the list

```
video/avc
video/3gpp
video/mp4v-es
audio/3gpp
audio/amr-wb
audio/mp4a-latm
audio/flac
audio/mp4a-latm
```

Using the method suggested by fadden(adb shell cat /system/etc/media_codecs.xml), I got the following

```
<MediaCodec name="OMX.WMT.decoder.h263" type="video/3gpp" >
        <Quirk name="requires-allocate-on-output-ports" />
        </MediaCodec>

<MediaCodec name="OMX.WMT.decoder.avc" type="video/avc" >
        <Quirk name="requires-allocate-on-output-ports" />
        </MediaCodec>

<MediaCodec name="OMX.WMT.decoder.mpeg2v" type="video/mpeg2" >
        <Quirk name="requires-allocate-on-output-ports" />
        </MediaCodec>

<MediaCodec name="OMX.google.mp3.decoder" type="audio/mpeg" />
<MediaCodec name="OMX.google.amrnb.decoder" type="audio/3gpp" />
<MediaCodec name="OMX.google.amrwb.decoder" type="audio/amr-wb" />
<MediaCodec name="OMX.google.aac.decoder" type="audio/mp4a-latm" />
<MediaCodec name="OMX.google.g711.alaw.decoder" type="audio/g711-alaw" />
<MediaCodec name="OMX.google.g711.mlaw.decoder" type="audio/g711-mlaw" />
<MediaCodec name="OMX.google.vorbis.decoder" type="audio/vorbis" />

<MediaCodec name="OMX.google.mpeg4.decoder" type="video/mp4v-es" />
<MediaCodec name="OMX.google.h263.decoder" type="video/3gpp" />
<MediaCodec name="OMX.google.h264.decoder" type="video/avc" />
<MediaCodec name="OMX.google.vpx.decoder" type="video/x-vnd.on2.vp8" />
```

Now I am suspecting that not every decoder declared in media_codecs.xml has been actually implemented.

Update[2015-06-13]

Very useful information provided by @fadden:

[CDD sections 5.1.1 - 5.1.3 "Video Codecs"](http://static.googleusercontent.com/media/source.android.com/en/us/compatibility/android-cdd.pdf) list all audio, image and video codecs that all Android devices are required to support.  I am not sure how many devices meet the requirement.  My two Android devices miss many required codecs.

Comment: It should be something like this one: http://www.freeformatter.com/mime-types-list.html

Comment: see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaCodecInfo.html

Comment: As I mentioned in my comment to the answer, how can I get the MIME type string of each obtained MediaCodecInfo?

Comment: in the link i posted there is an example method `private static MediaCodecInfo selectCodec(String mimeType)`, have you seen it?

Comment: I was asking how to get a complete list of all possible MIME type strings supported by Android, not how to use a MIME type that I already know.

Comment: ok so what is unclear in 4 methods provided by MediaCodecInfo? did you read them?

Comment: Yes, I have read it multiple times.  Could you point me to the specific location of the list of all the MIME types supported by Android that I was asking for?

Comment: iterate over all codecs,  inside the loop iterate over all mime types returned from getSupportedTypes()

Comment: OK, I got your point. Perhaps finding a decent Android device and doing what you mentioned will generate a fairly inclusive list that I was looking for.  Thank you.

Comment: you can try emu as well,  my genymotion 4.4 returns three dozens of mimetypes

Comment: I got only 8 from Asus MeMO Pad (see the edited post).

Comment: this is my emu 4.4 list http://pastebin.com/epd2bRvV

Answer (score 1, accepted):

List of codecs is completely dependent on a particular device. You have to enum all available codecs using [MediaCodecList](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaCodecList.html) and call MediaCodec.createDecoderByType for the right one.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  How can I get the MIME type string of each obtained MediaCodecInfo? Is the list the I mentioned in my comment what I should use?  I was asking the question because I had some codecs in my mind and wanted to try them.  If I see the list all possible MIME types supported by Android, I will know what to pick.

Comment: That doesn't make sense -- there is no list of "all possible MIME types" because anyone can define their own (starting with "x-"). You can see the list for a particular device with `adb shell cat /system/etc/media_codecs.xml`, but there is no such thing as a fixed list of types supported by all Android devices.

Comment: @fadden Thanks for the clarification. In other words, Android does not specify any minimum codec support; an app cannot assume an Android device support any codec.  This is my understanding now.

Comment: What originally motivated me to ask this question is that I had a decoder type in mind, and I wanted to find out the MIME type I need to use in an Android app. As my understanding now, there is no minimum codec requirement or recommended codec implementation, so I can just find the MIME type from any list such as the one mentioned in my comment, and try it in the code to see the luck.

Comment: There is a difference between "tell me all codecs Android supports" and "tell me which codecs all Android devices support". The latter is addressed in the CDD section 5.1.3. "Video Codecs": http://static.googleusercontent.com/media/source.android.com/en/us/compatibility/android-cdd.pdf .

Comment: @fadden  Thanks a lot!  That is the most useful information for my question.  The only minor downside is that it does not list corresponding MIME types, so one has to find out them by other means.  It is not a big deal.