# Is there a way to retrieve the limits of a MediaCodec instance?

Tags: android, android-mediacodec

Let's use one example to explain this. Suppose a MediaCodec instance is created as following:

```
MediaCodec.createDecoderByType("video/avc");
```

It is configured with an instance of MediaFormat.  We know the decoder has the following limits by [checking media_codecs.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30610609/type-list-of-mediacodec-createdecoderbytype-string-type):

```
<MediaCodec name="OMX.rk.video_decoder.avc" type="video/avc">
    <Limit name="size" max="4096x2160" min="176x144"/>
    <Limit name="alignment" value="8x8"/>
    <Limit name="block-size" value="16x16"/>
    <Limit name="blocks-per-second" max="244800" min="1"/>
    <Limit name="bitrate" range="1-10000000"/>
    <Feature name="adaptive-playback"/>
</MediaCodec>
```

Is there a way to find the resolution limits (176x244 - 4096x2160) programatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about VideoCapabilities gotten from MediaCodec.getCodecInfo()?

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaCodecInfo.VideoCapabilities.html

Comment: Though it is supported by API 21 and above unfortunately, it may be the best we can get.  The app supports API 16 and up.  Thank you.